# How to make sidebar menu in iOS application?

Tags: ios

I want to create side bar menu in iOS application like android using xib not by storyboard?
please help me on above.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a slide menu by using [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu)
 from git hub.

There are provide you a simple demo application also. Try to use this

Comment: @iPhoneDev always Welcome.